# PHP Apache phpinfo hide environment variables

Tags: apache, obfuscation, php

Is it possible to obfuscate or remove environment variables from phpinfo?

If not, is the only alternative to display the phpinfo function?

Thinking about it further, someone could easily print_r($_SERVER) and get the credentials as well.  What would be a solution to this?

**clarification**
This is in regards to Apache Environment Variables.

Comment: Just as a counter point, IMO, the ability to create and run the code above on the server has further implications than the output of `print_r($_SERVER)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Suhosin patch](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/index.html) does this:

> Ignores GET, POST, COOKIE variables with the following names:
>   GLOBALS, _COOKIE, _ENV, _FILES, _GET, _POST, _REQUEST
>   _SERVER, _SESSION, HTTP_COOKIE_VARS, HTTP_ENV_VARS
>   HTTP_GET_VARS, HTTP_POST_VARS, HTTP_POST_FILES
>   HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, HTTP_SERVER_VARS, HTTP_SESSION_VARS

other than that, I am not aware of a way to cleanly hide those variables.

That said, it shouldn't be really necessary in the first place - external visitors shouldn't be able to run `phpinfo()`, or dump arbitrary variables.

Comment: enabling suhosin and restarting apache still allows $_SERVER to be printed out.

Comment: @Spechal it probably needs activating through a configuration option. Sadly, apparently, the [Wiki](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html) on the topic is not up to date - it is missing `suhosin.server.strip` for example which I know exists, and blocks XSS attacks through $_SERVER. I can't currently see a resource that lists *all* the available options, and their [forum](http://forum.hardened-php.net/) is down - sorry

Comment: The concern comes from developers having credentials to the database.  It seems absurd since they need the credentials to access the database, but the higher ups don't want the developers to know what the credentials are.

Comment: @Spechal I see. But if the environment variables are removed or unset, the PHP script can no longer use them, can it?

Comment: Exactly.  Is seems to me the answer is, for my situation, no.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `flags` parameter to determine which sections are displayed/omitted.

Environment variables are value `16`.  The maximum value is `127`; so to only omit environment variables, send value `111`.

Show everything

- `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
- `<?php phpinfo(127); ?>`
- `<?php phpinfo(-1); ?>`
- `<?php phpinfo(INFO_ALL); ?>`
- `<?php phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL | INFO_CREDITS | INFO_CONFIGURATION | INFO_MODULES | INFO_ENVIRONMENT | INFO_VARIABLES | INFO_LICENSE); ?>`

Show only environment variables

- `<?php phpinfo(16); ?>`
- `<?php phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT); ?>`

Show everything EXCEPT environment variables

- `<?php phpinfo(111); ?>`
- `<?php phpinfo(INFO_ALL & ~INFO_ENVIRONMENT); ?>`

### Constants

```txt
Name (constant)     | Value | Description
INFO_GENERAL        |  1    | The configuration line, php.ini location, build date, Web Server, System and more.
INFO_CREDITS        |  2    | PHP Credits. See also phpcredits().
INFO_CONFIGURATION  |  4    | Current Local and Master values for PHP directives. See also ini_get().
INFO_MODULES        |  8    | Loaded modules and their respective settings. See also get_loaded_extensions().
INFO_ENVIRONMENT    | 16    | Environment Variable information that's also available in $_ENV.
INFO_VARIABLES      | 32    | Shows all predefined variables from EGPCS (Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server).
INFO_LICENSE        | 64    | PHP License information. See also the » license FAQ.
INFO_ALL            | -1    | Shows all of the above.
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#flags)

Comment: I appreciate the resurrection and nostalgia, but how does this stop the output of superglobals? There are too many ways to get to the data and technology has advanced enough to make this a non-issue for anyone or company using modern best practices. e.g. Multiple environments, tokens, secrets, etc...

Comment: Because it’s often still good enough. And passing information in env vars is still valid use case,. Having a info webpage somewhere for quick and dirty checks is also normal.